# How to count items of meta query?

Tags: meta-query, count

I have manually edited a WordPress WooCommerce hook which hides all out of stock products. The problem is I don't know how to count items found.

I tried `$query->count` but no result.

My code:

```
function hide_products($query) {
    $meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' );
    $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'       => '_stock_status',
            'compare'   => 'NOT IN',
            'value'     => 'outofstock'
    );
    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$query->found_posts may be what you are looking for from the code reference:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/

Note that meta_query expects nested arrays, even if you only have one query. You may need to use:

```
 $meta_query[0][] = array( .....
```

You should also take care with the form of the original query. If there are one or more relations defined, you will need to insert your new conditions into the correct relation array.

Comment: `$query->found_posts` always returns "0" :( @Mark

Comment: It sounds like the query is returning 0 posts which indicates a problem with the query itself. I have updated my answer to include a reference to the required meta_query array structure.